# Exporting multiple animations (tracks) in a single JSON file for THREE.js from 3DS MAX

Tags: json, animation, three.js

In the ['Animation / Skinning / Blending' Three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending), the JSON model (the Marine) has multiple animation tracks (idle, walk and run). These are stored in an "animations" array in the JSON file.

My question is two-fold... Firstly, how do you "label" the animations in 3DS MAX? I tried using an FBX Multi Take plugin which does allow me to add some marking. They are present when I re-import the FBX file back into Max but do not show up when I try to export to JSON... which is my next question....

How do you then export these animation states? When I use the 'ThreeJSAnimationExporter' from within 3DS MAX, there is no option to define any animation tracks (nor will it pick up the ones I defined in the question above), it just exports everything into 1 animation. This is stored in an "animation" (not "animations") array in the resulting JSON file?

The JSON file of the Marine must have been created somehow... can it be done in MAX? If it is only possible in Blender then is there any way I can get my models and animations from 3DS MAX to Blender as I am trained in MAX and don't particularly want to learn Blender, even though it does look very good these days.

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I am using the MAX exporter that ships with r71 of THREE.js.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get this working but it requires a lot of inelegant hacking of JSON files and excessive file duplication in MAX. Basically I have created multiple MAX files with the same rig, skin, weights, UV's and materials. I then animated each track of animation and export it using the existing ThreeJSAnimationExporter. I then open up the JSON files, extract the animation entries and combine them into a single JSON file with an "animations" property array instead of a single "animation" property. You can then rename the animation segments from 'Action' to something more useful.

If anyone has a more elegant solution I would love to hear it.

I would also love it if the clever person who created the original ThreeJSAnimationExporter script could create a new script called ThreeJSBlendedAnimationExporter which allows for a simple animation track input system, it would only need a start frame, end frame and animation label for each animation track (segment). And for the love of god, also address the smoothing while you're at it :)